# why is the while loop executing twice?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Please help me understand why the while loop prompts the statement "enter am or pm" twice. I need it to ask only once and wait for an input. Only if the input in invalid, should the loop execute again.

```
System.out.println(" ");

int startHour=0;

boolean validAnswerOne=false;

while (validAnswerOne == false){ 

  System.out.println("Enter the starting hour: ");

  startHour = input.nextInt();

  if (startHour<=12){

    validAnswerOne=true;

  }
}


String validAnswerTwo = "False";

while (validAnswerTwo.equals("False"))
{

  System.out.println("Enter am or pm: ");

  String time = input.nextLine();

  time = time.toLowerCase();


  if (time.equals("am") || time.equals("pm"))

  {

    validAnswerTwo="True";

  }


}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. After wrapping this in a trivial class and defining `input` to be a `Scanner` referencing `System.in`, the code works as intended.

Comment: Can you post your output, it's likely you're calling the posted code block twice. Sidebar, why not use a Boolean for the `validAnswer` flag?

Comment: I have updated the code, please check it out. I can't use another boolean because my teacher want us to show a variety of ways to do while loop conditions

Comment: If you write the code twice, then it's going to run twice. I don't understand where your confusion is coming from here. And on a side note, if your teacher things strings whose value is `"True"` or `"False"` is a remotely good way to represent Booleans, then you desperately need a new teacher.

Comment: how do I not make "Enter am or pm: " pop up twice?

Comment: Now I understand what's going on. Check out the link above.

Comment: ill try it out. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: it works. just had to change input.nextLine(); to input.next();

Comment: Curiously, this similar question has the same nextLine problem on the same sort of question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67392706/why-do-i-get-two-errors-when-comparing-strings-elapsed-time/67392866?

Comment: I still wouldn't use "True" or "False" string flags, use something like `while (!time.equals("am") && !time.equals("pm"))` and remove the flag all together. Might also be good to use `equalsIgnoreCase` so `'PM' == 'pm'`, just suggestions.